# MigraDoc text overflow into next page header

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I'm using MigraDoc to create letters in PDF for batch printing. That means I have multiple businesses that need to be notified for listing approval. I have created a template with generic information and I'm filling the details of the letter for each business in a foreach loop like this:

```
   public TemplateClass(string title, string subject, string author, string memo_field)
    {
        try
        {
            //---------------------------------------------------
            // Set up the document and section
            //--------------------------------------------------
            _document = new Document();
            _section = new Section();

            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            // Define the margins, style
            //--------------------------------------------------------------
            this.DefineBorder();
            this.DefineStyle(_document);
            this.FillHeaderAndFooter(memo_field);              
        }
        catch { }
    }

private void FillHeaderAndFooter(string memo_field)
    {
        //------------------------------------------------
        // Add the main section of the document
        //-----------------------------------------------------
        this._section = this._document.AddSection();
        {
            this._section.PageSetup.Orientation = Orientation.Portrait;
            this._section.PageSetup.PageFormat = PageFormat.Letter;
            this._section.PageSetup.OddAndEvenPagesHeaderFooter = true;

            //-----------------------------------------------
            // Add the header
            //-----------------------------------------------
            Image primaryImage = this._section.Headers.Primary.AddImage(Image.png");
            primaryImage.Height = "4.0cm";
            primaryImage.LockAspectRatio = true;
            primaryImage.RelativeVertical = RelativeVertical.Line;
            primaryImage.RelativeHorizontal = RelativeHorizontal.Margin;
            primaryImage.Top = ShapePosition.Top;
            primaryImage.Left = ShapePosition.Center;
            primaryImage.WrapFormat.Style = WrapStyle.Through;

            //------------------------------------------------
            // Add the header to the section
            //------------------------------------------------
            this._section.Headers.Primary.Add(this.Header());
            this._section.Headers.EvenPage.Add(this.Header());

            this._section.Footers.Primary.Add(this.Footer());
            this._section.Footers.EvenPage.Add(this.Footer());
        }
    }

public void GenerateLetters()
{
    template = new TemplateClass("", "", "", "Business Letter");
        {
            int i = 0;
            base.DocumentName = "Business Letter";
            var businesses = new List<Business>() { new Business() { ID=333, Name="XYZ", Address = "123 Main St" }, new Business() { ID=666, Name="PQR", Address="123 Main St"}}

            foreach (var business in businesses)
            {                    
                template.ReportSection.Add(AddBusinessInfo(business));
                template.ReportSection.Add(FillTopSection());
                template.ReportSection.Add(FillMessage());                   

                template.ReportSection.Add(FillDetails(business));
                template.ReportSection.Add(FillBottomSection());
                template.ReportSection.Add(FillSignature());

                if (i != businesses.Count)
                    template.ReportSection.AddPageBreak();

                i++;
            }
}
```

I am not sharing the code for some of the private methods that are called here.
FillDetails(business) is a Table that could have one row or multiple rows. This table information and the content below it is pushed over to next page that has header and it overlaps on it.

I can either skip the the header and footer information from second page onwards  for each business or avoid the overlap with header and somehow keep the body of the letter to be static size.

Answer (score 0):

When using MigraDoc you have to set a top border that is large enough to hold the header. If the header is larger than the reserved area then header and body may overlap and MigraDoc cannot prevent this.

Having headers on the first page only is another option.

Comment: I would like to have header on just first page but footer on all pages per business. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Specify that you want a different first-page header/footer (DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter). Set both header and footer for first page, only set footer for standard pages (Primary header/footer).

Comment: As you can see in my code, i have added a Section in FillHeaderAndFooter() that is defined in template class. Do i need to move this code to the other class and set DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter property in GenerateLetters()?

Comment: I only see code snippets and cannot analyse them completely. You may have to start a new section for every new logical document, even if you combine several logical documents in a single PDF. This way each logical document will start with its own first page.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It is now placing the header on just the first page. I wanted first page per business. Each business can have multiple pages depending on content. I have multiple businesses and the letters are built in loop. I need to have header on every single business.

Comment: See my comment above: start a new section for each new business and each business will start with a logical first page with a header.